# Java class naming convention

Tags: java, android, naming-conventions

I have the next situation:

In my current android project, I have packages: `api`, `persistence`(local db), `ui`.

In each of these packages I have classes. For example, classes with the same name `Group` exist in each package.

- package

  - ui

    - Group
  - api

    - Group
  - persistence

I need to map `api` class to `ui` in some mapper class and the bad things happend:

One class has import on the top of class and another has import inline.

```
import package.data.Group;

public class MyClass{
    package.ui.Group myGroup;
    Group myOtherGroup;
}
```

Want to know if exist some name convention for different modules.

Should I:

- keep the name `Group` and use full class name?
- Give my classes another name like `GroupEntity`, `GroupView`? If so, is there any convention?

Thanks

Comment: by `model`, you mean class?

Comment: yes class, object, entity )))

Answer (score 0):

You can find all of the naming conventions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html):

Here is what you want copied to ensure if the page goes down you still have an answer :

Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations.

Examples:

```
class Raster; 
class ImageSprite;
```

Comment: Thanks for source but i mean next: for data module: GroupEntity, for ui module: GroupModel

Comment: "text"? - i write "next" :))